# Problem in displaying in LWC data from Rest API

Tags: rest-api, lightning-web-components, json

While working with an api, I get the response in the APEX debugs, but was unable to display data in LWC.

APEX:

```
public with sharing class myReportController {

public static String Response { get; set;}
public static String Headers { get; set; }

@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static void myReportFetchMethod() {
    getAndParse('GET');
}    
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static void getAndParse(String GET) {
    String serviceEndpoint= 'https://mywebsite/endpoint';
    // Get the XML document from the external server
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request.setEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);

    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');

    request.setTimeout(120000); 
    HttpResponse res = http.send(request);

    System.debug(res.getBody());
    response=res.getBody();
}    
}
```

JS Controller:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import myReportFetchMethod from '@salesforce/apex/myReportController.myReportFetchMethod';

export default class myReportController extends LightningElement {
@track accounts;
@track error;

@wire(myReportFetchMethod)
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.accounts = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        console.log('TEST: '+this.accounts);
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.accounts = undefined;            
    }
}


}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card  title="My Report">
    <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" >

        <template if:true={accounts}>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                Attribute 1 - {account.A}
                Attribute 1 - {account.B}
                Attribute 1 - {account.C}
                Attribute 1 - {account.D}             
            </template>
        </template>

    </lightning:accordion>
   </lightning-card>
   </template>
```

JSON:

```
[
{
"A": "Block A",
"B": 164359,
"C": 515,
"D": 3173,
},
{
"A": "Block B",
"B": 101739,
"C": 0,
"D": 11591,
 }
]
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks! 
I hope everyone is doing great during this lockdown. Hope everything will be alright soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you generate an apex Message class for the response based on your JSON. For the JSON you have posted an apex class can be generated as shown below

```
public class ResponseWrapper{
  public String A;  //Block A
  public Integer B; //164359
  public Integer C; //515
  public Integer D; //3173
}
```

Then you can send this response to your front end in more defined way by changing below code

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<ResponseWrapper> myReportFetchMethod() {
    getAndParse('GET');
}    
  public static List<ResponseWrapper> getAndParse(String GET) {
  String serviceEndpoint= 'https://mywebsite/endpoint';
 // Get the XML document from the external server
  Http http = new Http();
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

  request.setEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);

  request.setMethod('GET');
  request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');

  request.setTimeout(120000); 
  HttpResponse res = http.send(request);

  System.debug(res.getBody());
  response=res.getBody();
  return (List<ResponseWrapper>) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<ResponseWrapper>.class)
}
```

> Notice that your auraEnabled methods are no more void methods and instead they return a list.

Then once you have data you can use the wire methods as you have to show the data on your front end component.

Comment: Hi @mohith I tried your way and it works. Thanks for the answer. I have a question. Is it always required to write a wrapper? Can't I pass a collection (map, list) and iterate over it on HTML? Probably we want to keep the UI as simple as possible?

Comment: You can also use Maps should be fine.I prefer a wrapper as it makes it easy to trace the output .If your json keys are dynamic then maps are preferred